# jquery twelve hour model is not working on chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am working with flot jquery library to draw a chart

this is my code

```
chartOptions = {
               xaxis: {
                   timeformat: "%H",
                   twelveHourClock: true,
```

as you see, i set the `twelveHourClock` option to `true` and yet I still get results like 14 18 20 ...

why please?

#### Update 1

I already tried to use `%I %p` in `timeformat` but then I got the following results, please check that the bellow values should be 8am 10am 12 ..... 8 pm

[image]

Comment: @monkeyinsight okay I will take a print screen and update the question, just a minute please

Comment: try to remove `timeformat` at all

Comment: @monkeyinsight when I removed the timeformat and kept the twelvehour options. I got `08:00am 10:00 am 14:00pm 20:00pm` .... but I need to have `8am 10am 12 2pm` with out the minutes, got me please?

Comment: create fiddle, can't debug from comments

Comment: @monkeyinsight i don't know how to make a jsfiddle with all the libraries that the flot takes. however, I will try

Comment: @monkeyinsight http://jsfiddle.net/z6eujjwf/2/ the code is in javascript section, please add the required library because I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: @monkeyinsight I need to take a break for 15 minutes then I will be with you again. appreciate your help and efforts with me.

Comment: @monkeyinsight updated one  http://jsfiddle.net/z6eujjwf/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59465/discussion-between-monkeyinsight-and-agnieszka-polec).

Comment: @monkeyinsight I will leave it as it is now because I have so many other things to do . really appreciate your time and efforts with me. However, I will tell you when I work back on that point

Comment: @monkeyinsight could you help me here please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349545/flot-jquery-is-it-possible-to-draw-this-kind-of-chart

Answer (score 0):

For zero padded 12 hour format,

```
  xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%I %p",
        tickSize: [1, "hour"],
        twelveHourClock: true,

    }
```

Comment: I already tried that and I already showed you the result in the question

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec Now I have updated my answer, check if it works for you